# How to apply custom OSM map style in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, openstreetmap

I have a small web mapping application based on PostGIS/GeoServer/OpenLayers.

I'm overlaying few WMS layers served by GeoServer and using OpenStreetMap as a background.

In OpenLayers OSM is simply called as:

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM");  
map.addLayer(osm);
```

How could I display OSM basemap in shades of grey to accentuate my WMS layers?

Is there a way to use existing styles from CloudMade's [Style Editor](http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor) for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/index.html) library might be another option.

```
<script>
var map = new L.Map('map');

var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/22677/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
cloudmadeAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade',
cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution});

map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.5, -0.09), 13).addLayer(cloudmade);

</script>
```

Where '22677' in the URL declaration is a reference for the style created in S[tyle Editor](http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor).

([Source](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/custom-icons.html))

Answer (score 6):

With the help of http://mapstraction.com/ API

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://developers.cloudmade.com/attachments/download/58/cloudmade.js" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/mapstraction/mxn/raw/master/source/mxn.js?(openlayers)"
  type="text/javascript"></script>



  map.getMap().addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.CloudMade('CloudMade', {
  key: 'YOUR_CLOUDMADE_API_KEY',
  styleId: '26167'
}));
```

source:

http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/1479986159/using-cloudmade-tiles-on-openlayers-maps-with